# Invalid receiver type for NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  NSLog(@"bla %@", [section count]);

  return [possessions count];
  }

Does anyone know how to implement a simple NSLog because I am getting an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLog(@"bla %d", section)`

NSInteger is basically just an int (but with marginally better-known characteristics).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the most used format specifiers:

- %d or % D for integer (int)
- %f for float
- %@ for String (in general)

You can see the other format specifiers here : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

section is of type NSInteger. NSInteger type declared variables does'nt have function with name count. You can print section value with below code.

`NSLog(@"bla %d",section)`